# Find target bounding rectangle while bing map view is changing

Tags: wpf, bing-maps, bounding-box

We are using WPF Bing Maps to visiualize clustered data. We are trying to update data on every OnViewChangeOnFrame event (because there is a significant delay in OnViewChangeEnd). However zooming and updating on every frame leads to "jerking" effect. The idea is to find out the target boundary rectangle OnViewChangeStart and update data only once in the beginning of zoom or pan for the target settings.

However there is a problem Bing Maps - Map class does not support TargetBoundingRectangle property. Is there an algorithm knowing viewportsize, target zoomlevel and target center to calculate TargetBoundingRectangle or maybe another Map property which has it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got an [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols/thread/34140328-5cbf-4260-a0c2-78e93302a79c/#34140328-5cbf-4260-a0c2-78e93302a79c) from MSDN forums.

WPF Bing Maps does not provide target boundary property right now.